# IntelliJ - "Go To -> Implementation(s)" goes to import statements instead of the actual file

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, ide

I am working on a TypeScript Project in IntelliJ.

When I performed the "Go To -> Implementation(s)" on a parent class such as line 22, I was expecting it would take me to the actual file where the parent class ComponentAlarmsStack resides. However, it just brought me to the imported name on line 6. It has been working as expected since longer than I can remember. Then all the sudden it stopped working and just kept sending me to the imported line. Now I have to do "Go To -> Implementation(s)" again on line 6 in order to go to the actual file. Anyone has any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Note: Java project seems to be working fine (i.e. hitting "Go To -> Implementation(s)" goes directly to the file, instead of going to the import statements like it did in TypeScript.)

[image]

Comment: unfortunately the issue is not reproducible for us. Most probably the actual class definition can't be resolved for some reason. Please share a sample project that reproduces the issue as requested in https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/16256359401490